# Device gets stuck after terminating bluetooth app

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement an app that reads data from a bluetooth device (a GlobalSat BT-338 GPS receiver). I have followed the instructions from the [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

The greatest problem is that after connecting and then disconnecting from the bluetooth device, if I terminate the app in whatever way, my device (LG E720, Android 2.2) gets completely stuck. The only way to unblock it is removing and replacing the battery!

These are some different ways I happen to use to terminate the app (the first one I can not avoid):

- From eclipse, run a new version of the app; this causes an automatic termination of the previous version running on my device: device stuck;
- From Eclipse DDMS screen, perform a "Stop process" on my app: device stuck;
- From the device itself: Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> BluetoothTest -> Terminate: device stuck

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the bluetooth stack on that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears my LG device needed a firmware upgrade, from V10a to V10b.
Easy to do from the LG support site, the procedure takes around 20 minutes.
In my case this completely solved the "device stuck" problem, which was my most important source of trouble in bluetooth connectivity.
V10b not only upgrades the firmware, but also the O.S. version, from 2.2 to 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quickly solution, maybe you should try to disable the BluetoothAdapter after disconnecting both devices:

```
// Your code for disconnect both devices
// ..........
// Disable the Bluetooth Adapter    
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
```

This is not the best solution because after every disconnection you need to re-enable the adapter, but it could work.

From now on, you can't connect or discover new devices using Bluetooth until you enable it again.

Comment: Hmmm... disabling the bluetooth manually does not solve the problem, so I'm not sure it would work programmatically. Moreover, the disable function requires a BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission, which I would like not to use. Thank you for you suggestion anyway.

By the way, the device is not entirely stuck; I have discovered that it is only veeeeery slowed down; with great patience I am even able to turn it off by regular means, without removing the battery. I can not find any similar issue on the web; it may really be a bug in my device bios. I will try with another android device, just to check.

Comment: I have discovered that there actually is a manual operation that avoids the problem: 1) unpair the bluetooth device; 2) disable bluetooth; 3) Terminate the app. This is absolutely unpractical, because then I have to re-pair the bluetooth device, and manually enter the password.

Comment: I have also installed a couple of apps from Play Store, having the same purpose: receiving data from a bluetooth GPS. They are affected by the same problem. So I am afraid the problem is definitely with my device model or O.S. version.

Comment: As Chris said in the comment in your main question, it could be a bug with Bluetooth's stack on your OS version. Can you check if your app have the same behaviour in another device with other OS version?